# Visual studio 2010 professional errer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have intalled `Silverlight5_Tools` and then I can't any more get my solution explorer and get this errer

An exception occurred during the construction of the contents of this frame. This information can be saved by running the application with the / log on the command line, which stores results in "C: \ Users \ studio \ AppData \ Roaming \ Microsoft \ VisualStudio \ 10.0 \ ActivityLog.xml."

Détails de l'exception :
System.OutOfMemoryException: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY))
   à System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()